# Can not use "startx" to strat my raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, linux, raspberry-pi

Today when I tried to start my raspberry pi, it doesn't work and say this in my screen:

`[warn] Root filesystem has insufficient free space; mounting tmpfs on /tmp ... (warning)
...
[FAIL] /etc/init.d/mysql:ERROR:The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full! ... failed!
[Fail] startpar:service(s) returned failure:mysql ... failed!`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates there isn't enough space left on the SD card.  You can do some of the following

- make sure the SD card is properly seated
- remove old log files
- remove unnecessary packages
- remove unbessary files
- get a bigger SD / micro SD card and install the OS

Restart the raspberry pi (so services have enough to start up without errors )
Login and run startx

Comment: I tried to remove the old log files by 'cd /var' and 'rm -rf log', but it prints 'rm:cannot remove .... Permission denied'. why is that?

Comment: A couple of points. First, the raspberry pi is running Linux . You'll need to pick up some of the basics of Linux / UNIX in order to navigate the pi.  You should learn about permissions and file ownership.  You could use sudo to execute a command as root, however please don't delete your /var/log folder itself (as your command would do). Deleting the folder will definitely cause other problems . Deleting or truncating  some of the files in the folder should be ok.